# How do I rename a SSD (NOT the label)?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, rename, firmware, nvme

How can I rename a SSD's actual name like its model name? I had used Sabrent Control Panel to check for a newer firmware on a non Sabrent NVMe, it said there was a firmware available, but I did not update it. Later that day I went into the motherboard BIOS and realized that my NON-SABRENT SSD was now called "Sabrent" while previously it showed up as "PCIe SSD"

FYI: I had two NVMe SSDs: Sabrent Rocket 4 NVMe 1TB and Inland Premium 512GB NVMe

The Inland drive got its real name which was "PCIe SSD" changed to "Sabrent"

Comment: Your firmware gets the names of the storage devices from the storage devices itself.  It really sounds like one of your drives is disabled, not recognized, or some option in the UEFI is not set correctly.

Comment: @LawrenceC Yes, I know, and I think that the Sabrent Control Panel somehow altered my firmware for the NVMe and got it changed.

Answer (score 0):

Open Device manager > Expand Disk Drives section. Choose your SSD and right-click > Properties. Then go to the Details tab. From the Property drop-down list choose Driver key and copy the value.

Now open Regedit as Administrator. Now go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum key and right-click > Permissions. Click Advanced > Check names and choose your user name. Now in Owner tab > Advanced check mark Replace owner on subcontainers and objects. In permissions box click Full control on your user name. You can skip all these by running `psexec -s -i regedit` (needs `psexec` from SysInternals) by running Regedit as SYSTEM user.

Now open the Find dialog (CTRL+F) and enter the value you copied. Click Find and it will take you to the value and then create new string value named FriendlyName and set its value to the **display name you want**. Now open device manager again and scan for hardware changes. It's better to restart.

Hope that helps

Comment: I have tried that and that only changes the setting in Windows, but it got changed everywhere, like even in the BIOS its default name has been changed.

Comment: same result as reported by user, this solution doesn't work.